# Separate values inside an array with commas

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [Customer] => Customer1
            [whatever] => XXXXX
            [names] => Carmen, Javier
        )
```

and I want the same array but in this way

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [Customer] => Customer1
            [whatever] => XXXXX
            [names] => Array ([0] => Carmen, [1] => Javier)

        )
```

I've tried this

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                if ($key == 'names') {
                    $value[$key] =(array_map('trim',explode(",",$val)));
                }
            }
        }
```

but it's not doing what I want

Comment: Maybe: `foreach ($data as $value) {` -> `foreach ($data as $outerKey => $value) {` and then do: `$data[$outerKey][$key]` instead of `$value[$key]` ...

Comment: Access `$value` by reference" rather than "by value": `foreach ($data as &$value) {`

Comment: @MarkBaker I didn't throw that one in, because otherwise just someone will complain about it, that you have to also unset the reference after the loop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it..I just needed to use

```
$value[$key][]
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify array in loop, you have to do it by reference or make its copy first and then operate on copy.

Reference way:

```
foreach ($data as &$value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == 'names') {
            $value[$key] =(array_map('trim',explode(",",$val)));
        }
    }
}
unset($value);
```

Comment: This really helped me a lot.. I don't know why we have to use values by reference inside the loop, maybe you could explain me. I've done this before but not using multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Julio You don't have to use reference. There is always other option, but if you modify content of array which you loop over, you can use reference. Reference allows you to work on content of array which you passed to foreach loop. Otherwise you work on copy of array. More about reference itself you can find in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need for your second foreach statement, also watch what your calling your variables, there is a lot of things called `$value` which is pretty meaningless, change `$value` into something that is meaningful to the data. The final thing I altered is I am passing in `$value` as a reference so I can update it within the foreach

```
$testData = [
    [
        'someKey' => 'someValue',
        'names' => "Foo, Bar",
    ],
    [
        'someKey' => 'someValue',
        'names' => "Fred, Wilma",
    ]
];

foreach ($testData as &$value) {
    if(isset($value['names'])) {
        $tempValue = $value['names'];
        $names = explode("," , $tempValue);
        $value['names'] = array_map('trim',  $names);
    }
}

unset($value);
var_dump($testData);
```

Hope that helps